# getting page values from linkedin using phantomjs and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to get users details from linked in using phantomjs and selenium

```
def getLinkedinData(self):
    result = {}
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs' ,service_args=service_args)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
    google_news_trends = []
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/pub/omkar-mujgond/5/aa0/b74")
    try:
        print driver.find_element_by_class_name('locality').text
    except:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Though the code is correct, I am getting

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name 'locality'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"97","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:47844","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"class name\", \"sessionId\": \"7e474060-2fab-11e5-b0d9-db8d38927a05\", \"value\": \"locality\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/7e474060-2fab-11e5-b0d9-db8d38927a05/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Comment: Have you taken a screenshot to see if you're on the correct page? Have you printed the page source to see if the element is there? Are you perhaps on the mobile page where this element never appears?

Comment: @ArtjomB.: I am on correct page, and yeah I am on web view page where this elements appears

Comment: @niper were you able to make it work. I am stuck in same problem and when I tried this using phantomjs I am getting empty html.

Comment: @nlper - Did you got this working?